# JMS Topic - Weblogic to Wildfly / JBoss migration

Tags: java, jboss, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have one of my Topics in WebLogic with overrides properties "Time-To Deliver Override" and "Delivery Mode Override"

[image: Topic Overrides Properties]

I'm working on a migration to WildFly server. I've declared the Topics in the standalone.xml under the ActiveMQ subsystem tag as following

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:8.0">
 ...
   <jms-topic name="MyTopic" entries="jms/MyTopic java:jboss/jms/MyTopic"/>
   <jms-topic name="MyTopicToOverride" entries="jms/OverTipic java:jboss/jms/OverTopic"/>
 ...
</subsystem>
```

But, I have no idea on how can I configure the equivalent of "Time-To Deliver Override" and "Delivery Mode Override" in standalone.xml for "MyTopicToOverride".

Do you have any idea on how can I do it, and how can I do it for one topic only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WildFly embeds [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/) as its JMS implementation, and ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't support overriding a message's time-to-deliver or delivery-mode. However, if it did they would be configured via an `address-setting` as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings).

You could potentially work-around this by implementing a [broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html) which performed the overrides you wanted. Although I'm not 100% certain that the WildFly configuration exposes the plugin configuration.

These seem like worthwhile features to implement. Feel free to open issues in the [ActiveMQ Artemis Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS).

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it in standalone.xml. I finally did it in java.

Comment: You didn't find a way to do *what* exactly in `standalone.xml`? Configure a broker plugin?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to configure a broker plugin in WildFly and since I found a solution in java, I didn't want to waste my time. Thank you for your help.